# Conditional URL rewriting

Tags: mod-rewrite

How can I use URL rewriting in .htaccess to redirect to different domains depending on the URL?

Examples:

- `http://ONE/` to `http://TWO/`
- `http://ONE/some_content` to `http://THREE/some_content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to work if you want to redirect the client:

```
# http://ONE/ to http://TWO/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    =one
RewriteRule ^$             http://two/ [R,L]

# http://ONE/some_content to http://THREE/some_content
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    =one
RewriteRule ^(.+)$         http://three/$1 [R,L]
```

If you prefer to proxy the requests, change the R flag to a P instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately it doesn't work.

The first case does not change the domain ONE in TWO
The second case brings a 404 error on the domain ONE

Here is my complete .htaccess

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =ONE
RewriteRule ^/$ http://TWO/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =ONE
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ http://THREE/$1 [R,L]

Is it something wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the htaccess part. You'll need to remove the initial slash from the RewriteRules, i.e. `^/` becomes only `^`

I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Woaw, thank you very much.
It's working now. I'm really happy. :-)